# Dynamic memory allocation in XV6 kernel

Tags: kernel, malloc, xv6

I want to implement a `Queue` struct (using `Node` struct, similiral to the `C` code [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/queue-linked-list-implementation/)) in files `Queue.c` and `Queue.h` in order to store processes in `proc.c` in `XV6` kernel.

I don't know how to to do it, since it requires to use `malloc`, but I can't use it inside methods which I call from the kernel.

What can I use instead, in order to implement and use the `Queue`?

Answer (score 1):

You will probably have to implement something similar to the user malloc code ([user/malloc.c](https://github.com/mit-pdos/xv6-riscv/blob/riscv/user/umalloc.c)), for the kernel. For example, look at the file [kernel/string.c](https://github.com/mit-pdos/xv6-riscv/blob/riscv/kernel/string.c). It's contents are very similar to [user/ulib.c](https://github.com/mit-pdos/xv6-riscv/blob/riscv/user/ulib.c). In this way, the kernel and user space have their own versions of functions like `memset`.

The code from *user/umalloc.c* cannot just be copied and pasted into a kernel version. You'll have to make tweaks for it to work in kernel space. For example changing how `morecore` [grows](https://github.com/mit-pdos/xv6-riscv/blob/9ead904afef8d060c2cc5cee6bd8e8d223de8c40/user/umalloc.c#L47) the space managed by the allocator...